# JavaScript basic regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split a string by the delimiter `\s` and `,` so that `'hello    , world , hi yes'` returns as `[ 'hello', 'world', 'hi', 'yes' ]`

Right now I'm using `str.split(/[\s,]+/)`, but the issue with this is that it doesn't compensate for falsely strings such as the empty string or a string that consists of only space.

That is, `''` returns `[ '' ]` and `' '` returns `[ '', '' ]`, but they should just return `[]`

Comment: use this `\w{1,}`   [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qfUBbf/1/)

Comment: Could  you please add the extra information that you provided in the answer in the question via an edit?  Once you have completed this I will delete my answer as it no longer will be a valid response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really only need a RegEx to detect the spaces:

```js
var s = 'hello    , world , hi, yes a b';
// Replace one or more spces with a comma
// Split on the commas
// Do a filtering loop over results
// Return any strings (into a new array) that have characters in them after a trim is performed
var result = s.replace(/\s+/g, ",").split(",").filter(word => { return word.trim() !== "" ; });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to add that \s is a delimiter by itself as well, so ``a b'` should return `['a','b']`

Comment: @thestateofmay Answer updated to address space delimiters as well.

Comment: @georg No. As you can see, you just need `filter` because `filter` also returns a new array, just like `map` does.

Comment: right! What about your "dont' need regex" statement now? ;)

Comment: Actually, you can do with re's at all, as in your first version: `.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).filter(x => x.length)`

Comment: @georg That would work if spaces weren't also considered delimiters, but it doesn't work here. If you notice, `a b` needs to become `a, b`, not `a  b`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus: yeah, right. Things are so complicated without regexes...

Answer (score 1):

When working with regexes, it's usually better to concentrate on what you want instead on what you don't want. In other words, use `match`, not `split`:

```js
s = 'hello    , world , hi, yes'
r = s.match(/[^\s,]+/g)
console.log(r)


s = '    '
r = s.match(/[^\s,]+/g)
console.log(r)
```

If you don't like `null` as the "empty" result, do

```
r = s.match(/[^\s,]+/g) || []
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression, that looks for zero or more spaces before and after the comma:

```
\s*,\s*
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/6wWQdB/1

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with a single line of JavaScript.  It is really simple.

```js
let testString = 'hello    , world , hi, yes';

let wordArray = testString.split(',').map(word => (word.trim()));

console.log(wordArray); // prints ['hello', 'world', 'hi', 'yes']
```

Comment: Best attempt at what the original question was.

Comment: Made a request for the question to be updated.  Once that happens I will remove my response.

Comment: The OP seems to be happy with what they've got anyways, let's move on ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a count of chars, for example, at least one:

```
'hello    , world , hi, yes'.split(/[\s,]+/)
```

Notice that split will always return at least one item = the entire string if no matches were found. So `''.split(/[\s,]+/)` will produce `['']`.